# Regarding the process swap IN core number in multi core system

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler, multicore, affinity, cgroups

Is there any way I can find how many processes swapped into particular core in a given period of time on multi core system ?

Say suppose, I have 8 core machine in which one process is hard affined to core 3 and would like to know how many times other process / interrupts kicked the hard affined process out of scheduler or in other way around how much time was provided to other process(es) to run on this core.

Hardware : e500v2; Linux : 2.6.34; Kernel : Preempt - OFF; Cgroups configured.

Note: The visibility of this core is provided to only one group and only this task/process is tagged against that group.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any idea on this question ?? Please shed some light.

Comment: You might be able to do something with ftrace or perf. Both have hooks into the Linux kernel and you might be able to hook into one of the scheduler functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found useful pointers on the below link, maybe useful for someone else who is looks for the same data/information.

http://cs.boisestate.edu/~amit/teaching/597/scheduling.pdf

https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l13.pdf

http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS01/OS/Lectures/Lecture08.pdf

Thank you.!

Comment: This is the memory swap. Nothing to do with the scheduler.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thanks for letting me know about incorrect link, by mistake memory swap link got pasted in this thred. Updated links which helped me to go further in terms of debugging and proflling the processes schedule in and out.